# When are parameters in a lambda expression prefered?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

This is kind of a weird question but it came up the other day and it has me thinking.

When is it preferable design to use lambda expressions in this form ".(x => x.Whatever)" verse ".(() => obj.Whatever)".

Consider the following extension methods.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string TryToGetTheString<T>(this T value, Func<T, string> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return method(value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "banana";
        }
    }

    public static string TryToGetTheStringTwo<T>(this T value, Func<string> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return method();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "banana";
        }
    }
 }
```

And the following self referencing class.

```
 public class testClass5000
 {
     private int? _id;
     public int? ID { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }

     private string _urgh;
     public string Urgh { get; set; }

     public testClass5000 tc5k { get; set; }
 }
```

Then using an extremely lazy process to avoid checking for nulls, while attempting to get a string (Urgh) from testClass5000, you could implement the extension methods and class like such,

```
    private void main()
    {
        var tc = new testClass5000();

        textBox1.text = tc.TryToGetTheString(x => x.tc5k.tc5k.tc5k.Urgh);

    }
```

However, since tc is declared locally the following also works.

```
    private void main()
    {
        var tc = new testClass5000();

        textBox1.text = tc.TryToGetTheStringTwo(() => tc.tc5k.tc5k.tc5k.Urgh);

    }
```

I am curious when `(x => x.tc5k.tc5k.tc5k.Urgh)` is necessary and when `(() => tc.tc5k.tc5k.tc5k.Urgh)` is preferable.

//////////////////////////////////////////

I did come up with the following scenario where passing the parameter seems preferable.

With the following extension methods.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T TestOne<T>(this T value, Func<T, T> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return method(value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static T TestTwo<T>(this T value, Func<T> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return method();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

And using the following code.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var firstValue = 5;
        var secondValue = 10;

        var resultOne = firstValue.TestOne(x => x + 1).TestOne(x => x * 2);
        //returns 12
        var resultTwo = secondValue.TestTwo(() => secondValue + 1).TestTwo(() => secondValue * 2);
        //returns 20
        var resultThree = secondValue.TestTwo(() => secondValue.TestTwo(() => secondValue + 1) * 2);
        //returns 22
    }
```

In this example .TestOne(x => x + 1).TestOne(x => x * 2) is preferable notation because to achieve the same thing without passing a paremeter you need to start nesting expressions.

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`!  In all of these cases I would opt to ommit the try/catch entirely, and let the calling code fail rather then silently hide the problem with a default return value.

Comment: Yeah I agree, this was just a quick hack to create a scenario where the question came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where the parameters are simply not the same as the original value you provided.

A crude example

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this string s,Action<string> action)
    {
        var something = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(i=> String.Format("{0}_{1}",s,i));
        foreach (var ss in something)
        {
            action(ss);
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
var something = "ABC123";

something.DoSomething(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
//Ignoring that we could do something.DoSomething(Console.WriteLine);
```

Obviously without the parameter you cant access the actual value you are insterested in, and the original value is of no use within this concept.

Answer (score 4):

Injecting the parameters values directly in the lambda is more costly, because the compiler has to create a special class just for this purpose.

If we exclude performance considerations, then I would say that injecting the parameter is easier to write (personal preference here), and keeping the parameters in the prototype ( (x,y) => // do something) is useful when you're not actually the one providing the value of the parameters. For instance, when using the Select Linq query. Or I often use that for load balancing scenarios (a lambda "service => service.SomeFunction()", then a special factory retrieve the service and execute the lambda).

Comment: +1: "when you're not actually the one providing the value of the parameters" is the crux of it.

Comment: The `x =>` version does not capture any variables, so a single static lambda can be re-used. The `()=>` version requires variable capture, which means a new lambda will be created each time it is called, and an extra level of indirection is invoked each time you access `tc` because the compiler needs to make sure that if your lambda does `tc = newValue`, that new value is visible to the enclosing function. Further discussion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/02/686456.aspx).